# ASP.NET mvc3 with an ASP.NET mvc4 Web API project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a solution with two projects:

> - An ASP.NET MVC3 Web project.
> - An ASP.NET MVC4  Web API project

I would like to know (if its possible) how to configure a route (for instance `/api/{controller}/`) in the first project (global.asax) in order to be able to use an ApiController on my api project. I dont know what's the routehandler used in a Web API project.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure a web-api route, go to the `WebApiConfig.cs` file and create a route.

Here's an example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

These two projects are separate entities.  It's not possible for them both to be hosted by the same server on the same port at the same time.  So, either the URL will be different for the projects, or the port will be different.  In either case, you wouldn't *route* to the other project, as much as *redirect* to the other project, the same way you would redirect to any other website.